# Uncountable subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ with property that every subset of $X$ with $n$ elements is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, baire-category, hamel-basis

$\textbf{Question}$: Show that there exist an uncountable subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with property that every subset of $X$ with $n$ elements is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt}$: For $n= 2$, if we take $X = \{(\cos \theta, \sin \theta): 0<\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}\}$, then $X$ has such property. But for $n\geq 3$, I can not find any way. Welcome for answer of this question.

Comment: What about the set of $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ where all coordinates of $x$ are _positive_?

Comment: For $n=3$, draw a small circle on the surface of the unit sphere

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^{n-2}\oplus\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: If you're interested in what $X$ can be, here are some follow-up questions you could ask: can $X$ be a 2-dimensional submanifold? What is the largest Hausdorff dimension $X$ can have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider all such subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (not necessarily uncountable). They form a poset under inclusion and it is easy to see that every chain has an upper bound (their union).
By Zorn's lemma, there exists a maximal subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^n$ with the required property. If $S$ were countable, then $\mathbb R^n$ would be a countable union of hyperplanes, and this is not true: [Show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be written as a countable union of proper subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284301/show-that-mathbbrn-cannot-be-written-as-a-countable-union-of-proper-subspa)

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: Very nice, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The set of vectors $(1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1})$ with $x > 0$ works, because the condition amounts to the fact that a Vandermonde determinant is nonzero.