# Is it possible that a vector space can be a finite union of proper subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $V_i$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ be non-zero subspaces of $V$. Is it possible that $V=\cup_{i=1}^n V_i?$

The underlying field is assumed to be infinite.

Comment: This is a classic problem.  The result can only hold if one of the $V_i$ is the entire space (assuming the vector space is over an infinite field).

Comment: I know the result for $n=2$ but not for arbitrary $n.$ Can we use induction?

Comment: Not only is this a classic problem, it is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: please give me the link.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145869/a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-cannot-be-covered-by-finitely-many-proper-subs/145876#145876

Comment: Indeed, it is a duplicate [A finite-dimensional vector space cannot be covered by minitel many proper subspaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145869/a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-cannot-be-covered-by-finitely-many-proper-subs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space over an infinite field $k$.  Assume $V=\cup_{i=1}^nV_i$, where $V_i$ are all proper subspaces.  Let $u\in V_1$, and take any $v\in V\setminus V_1$.  There are infinitely many vectors of the form $u+cv$ for $c\in k^*$, none of which are in $V_1$.  Since there are infinitely many of them, and only finitely many subspaces, there must be some $V_j$ containing at least two of them.  It follows that both $v$ and $u$ are in $V_j$ so that $V_1\subset \cup_{i=2}^nV_i$.

Continuing this process, we can show that $V=V_n$, contradicting the assumption that the subspaces are proper.

I guess the assumption that $k$ is infinite is a bit overkill.  We only need that there are at least as many elements in the field as subspaces in the union to derive a contradiction.  This shows that even over finite fields, we need at least as many subspaces as elements in the field to obtain such a decomposition.

Comment: So we don't need to exclude $(0)$?

Comment: It was a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145876/386889