# Let $V$ be any vector space over an infinite field. Are there proper subspaces $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that $V = \bigcup W_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ where $F$ is infinite. Are there proper subspaces $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that $V = \bigcup_{i \in I} W_i$  where $I$ is countable?

If $V$ is a vector space over a finite field with $\dim V > 1$, this is clearly true since $V$ has finitely many elements, we have $V = \bigcup \operatorname{span}(v)$ where $v \ne 0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145869/a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-cannot-be-covered-by-finitely-many-proper-subs?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10760/a-vector-space-over-r-is-not-a-countable-union-of-proper-subspaces?lq=1

Comment: Please check the suggestions of previous questions before posting.

Comment: @tessellation What suggestions?

Comment: Whenever you are asking  any question just above the space of writing stackExchange will automatically show you some suggestions, These are the questions asked previously about the topic you are posting. Just go through them to see if the question is already asked or not. In your case (in the two links above ) this question has already been asked twice. Its just to avoid repeattation  of any question.