# Find a linear functional such that vanishes on given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $v_1,v_2,...,v_k\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}.$ Show that there exists a linear functional $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(v_j)\neq 0$ for all $j.$

I just taking $f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for fixed $y\neq 0 $. This map is linear. But I am not sure whether it will work.

Comment: Your choice will not work. Consider a vector orthogonal to y. Unless you construct a y that is not orthogonal to any of your v1,...,vk.

Comment: what is ta vector. please can you tell clearly sir.

Comment: Suppose you have just one vector $v$.. Can you find a linear functional $f$ such that $f(v)\neq 0$?

Comment: ya, that place was i get struggle.

Comment: first think about single vector.. then try for more than one vector.. What linear functionals are you aware in case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: $f(x)=Ax$ where $A$ is any $n\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Hey.. Common... How is this different from $f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$..

Comment: This isn't different, but you have to actually pick a good $y$. Not all choices will work.

Answer (score 1):

The set of vectors orthogonal to $v_1$ forms a subspace $V_1$. Because $v_1\neq0$ the subspace $V_1$ is not all of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Similarly for all $i$, the set of vectors orthogonal to $v_i$ forms a proper subspace $V_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,k$.

At this point I refer you to the latter part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60719/11619), where I show that the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^kV_i$ is not all of $\Bbb{R}^n$ either. Can you do the rest with the inner product idea?

---

The argument works even if we had countably infinitely many vectors $v_i,i\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: The same argument later appeared [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/145897/11619). This link may be better for you because the parts dealing with finite fields was left out. Leaving the link to the older version into the answer.