# Finite Union of proper subspaces of $\mathbb C^2$ can equal to $\mathbb C^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

My instructor for Linear Algebra gave us a problem to think about but am quite unsure on how to approach it:

Let $V_1, V_2, ... V_{100}$ be $100$ proper subspaces of the complex vector space $V=\mathbb C^2$. Can it be possible that $\bigcup _{i=1}^{100} V_i = \mathbb C^2$?

Comment: What are the possible subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$? $\{0\}$, $\{z(\alpha_1,\alpha_2): z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ and what else?

Comment: Also related: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/10760/49437) and [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there are two cases, all $V_i$ are the same, then the union is a subspace to, and a proper one. The second case is that not all $V_i$ are the same, then the union of all $V_i$ is not closed under addition and can't be a vector space. I used here that we have a 2 dimensional vectorspace over an infinite field, so we have an infinite number of subspaces.

Proof the following Lemma:
Let $U_1,U_2$ be subspaces of a vectorspace $V$, then 
\[ U_1 \cup U_2 \]
is a subspace iff $U_1\subseteq U_2$ or $U_1 \supseteq U_2$

Comment: Allow me to disagree. Of course the union of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if it coincides with one of them. But if you consider the union of a finite number, greater than two, of subspaces in a finite vector space, this can be a subspace different from each of them. So any argument here has to use the fact that we are working over an infinite field.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I implicitly used that a 2 dimensional vector space over an infinite field does have infinite many proper subspaces, if you only have finitely many proper subspaces you are right.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I think I fixed it now, at downvoter is there still something to fix ?

Comment: I have never given a downvote in all my MSE life.

Comment: +1  Same for me, @Andreas: comments are so much better...

Comment: yeah when you get a comment you know at least what you have done wrong, I downvote rarely but never without a comment

Answer (score 1):

If $V_i$ has as equation $l_i(z,w)=a_iz+b_iw=0$, then the non-zero polynomial $P(z,w)=\prod^{100}_{i=1} l_i(z,w)$  of degree $100$ vanishes on $\bigcup^{100}_{i=1} V_i$.
Since a non-zero polynomial cannot vanish on the whole of $\mathbb C^2$, we have $\bigcup^{100}_{i=1} V_i\subsetneq \mathbb C^2$

Answer (score 0):

One has to be careful, because a finite vector space can  well be the union of finitely many proper subspaces. For instance the vector space of dimension two over the field with two elements is the union of three subspaces of dimension one.

Note first that each $V_i$ can be assumed to be one-dimensional. Add the subspace $V_{0} = \{ (0, a) : a \in \Bbb{C} \}$ to the $V_{i}$ for good measure, and suppose each $V_i \ne V_0$ for $i \ne 0$.

Then in each $V_i$ (with $i \ne 0$) there is a *unique* element of the form $(1, a_i)$. Choose an element $a \notin \{ a_i : i \in 1, \dots, 100 \}$. (Here of course we are using the fact that $\Bbb{C}$ is infinite.) Then $(1, a) \notin \bigcup_{i=0}^{100} V_i$, so $V \ne \bigcup_{i=0}^{100} V_i$.

So this works for any finite number of subspaces, and any infinite field.