# Vector space over an infinite field which is a finite union of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^n W_i$ where $W_i$'s are subspaces of a vector space $V$ over an infinite field $F$. Show that $V=W_r$ for some $1 \leq r \leq n$.

I know the result "Let $W_1 \cup W_2$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ iff $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$."

Now can I extend this to some $n$ subspaces.

I have some answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10760/a-vector-space-over-r-is-not-a-countable-union-of-proper-subspaces)
& [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces).

So before someone put it as a duplicate I want to mention that I want a proof of this problem using basic facts which we use in proving the mentioned result.

Comment: Well, the linked questions have answers with self-contained proofs for the infinite case. So what makes this question a non-duplicate?

Comment: In the first case the proof uses covering things which I don't know clearly. And in math overflow if you see "Steve D"s answer it uses basic techniques. But I have a question that how he gets the conclusion "so there is some $V_j, j≠1$, with infinitely many of these vectors, so it contains $y$, and thus contains $x$." I can't ask him in a comment because I am not a member in mathoverflow and can't wait for the answer untill $50$ reputations.

Comment: If you are unhappy with the answers in the question you linked to, would the answers to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60698/11619) be easier to follow?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a *really* elegant proof for the claim by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general result  is that if $\lvert K\rvert\ge n$, $V$ cannot be the union of $n$ proper subspaces (*Avoidance lemma for vector spaces*).

We'll prove that if $V=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n W_i$ and the $W_i$s are proper subspaces of $V$, then $\;\lvert K\rvert\le n-1$.

We can suppose no subspace is contained in the union of the others.

Pick $u\in W_1\smallsetminus\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\neq1} W_i$, and $v\notin W_1$. The set $v+Ku$ is disjoint from $W_1$, and it intersects each $W_i\enspace(i>1)$ in at most $1$ point (otherwise $u$ would belong to $W_i$). As this set is in bijection with $K$, there results that $K$ has at most $n-1$ elements.

Comment: Thanks thats why I was confused in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces that why in Steve D"s answer "there is some $V_j,j≠1$, with infinitely many of these vectors, so it contains $y$, and thus contains $x$." Is true because every $V_j$ should contain at most $1$ element.

Answer (score -2):

$V$  is  a  vector  space  over  an  infinite  field.
If $\ \ $   $\cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}=V$  is  a vector space  itself  then  from  what  you  already  know we  can  write $$W_{1}\subseteq W_{2}\subseteq W_{3}........\subseteq W_{n}$$  possibly  with  a  re-ordering  of  the  subspaces  $W_{i}$'s .

Then  what  do  we  see  here?  $W_{n}$  containing  the  other  subspaces  of  $V$. So  intuitively  we  could  suspect  that  $V=W_{n}$  might  be  the  thing .

Let's  prove  it. $$W_{n}\subseteq V$$  is known.  For  the  reverse  inclusion ; if possible  let  $$V\neq W_{n}$$ let $w$  be  a  vector such  that $$w\in V \ \  but\ \    w\notin W_{n}$$  . Now  $$\cup_{i=1}^{n} W_{i}=V$$  implies  $w$  is  in  $W_{i}$  for  some  $i=1,2...,n$. But  $$W_{i}\subseteq W_{n}$$ for  all  $i=1,2,....n$ .  Hence $$w\in W_{n}$$ . A  contradiction.  Thus  $$V\subseteq W_{n}$$  must  be  true. Hence  proved  $$V=W_{n}$$

Comment: Where do you use that the ground field is infinite? If you don't your proof must be wrong (because the result is wrong if $|F|\le n$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen :  Apologies, Sir. Actually  read  the  previous  comment  of  the  OP   and  had  infinite  field  in  mind. Should  have  wrote  it, I  agree.                                                                                                 I  have  added  one  line  to  my  answer .  If  there  is  still  some  mistake ,  please  point  out.

Comment: Yes, now you *mention* that $F$ should be infinite. But where do you *use* it? More to the point, how do you justify the "from what you already know" (it can't be justified)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen :I  meant  this "Let $W_1 \cup W_2$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ iff $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$." by  "  from  what  you  already  know" .  And  yes  ,  this  also  requires  an  infinite  field  to  be  true                                                                                                           Actually  OP's  question  was  wholly  $\mathcal over $ an  infinite  field, I  thought.

Comment: For my result can you prove your claim that the chain in $W_i$ comes?

Comment: @user152715 :  Sorry , I  don't  understand ,  which  part  exactly  are  you  referring  to?

Comment: Just proof how do you get $$W_{1}\subseteq W_{2}\subseteq W_{3}........\subseteq W_{n}$$?

Comment: @user118494 "Let $W_1\cup W_2$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ iff $W_1\subseteq W_2$ or $W_2\subseteq W_1$." happens to be true alo over finite fields and at any rate cannot readily be extended to $n>2$. Henc $W_1\subseteq \ldots \subseteq W_n$ is not something we already know