# Prove that $\mathbb R^n$ is not the union of finitely many its proper subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading *An Introduction to Algebraic Topology* by Rotman. After proving

**Theorem 2.7**: For every $k\geq 0$, euclidean space$\mathbb R^n$ contains $k$ points in general position,

the book remarked: There are other proofs of this theorem using induction on k. The key geometric observation needed is that $\mathbb R^n$ is not the union of only finitely many proper affine subsets .
I want to prove that observation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10760 or the answers at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26

Comment: I'm not sure if "proper affine subset" is a standard well-known definition... could you include what exactly it means, pls (affine subspace, maybe)?

Comment: @PeterFranek It means that its dimension is less than $n$.

Comment: user658532, not even a countable number of such sets could fill $\mathbb R^n$ because they have measure zero.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60698/11619). The same holds for $\Bbb{Q}$ without any measure theory or topology (though a countable union will obviously work in that case :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a field $F$ is such that $|F|\ge n-1$ why is $V$ a vector space over $F$ not equal to the union of $n$ proper subspaces of $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60698/if-a-field-f-is-such-that-leftf-rightn-1-why-is-v-a-vector-space-over)

Comment: @amsmath I got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Every affine proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ i contained in an affine hyperplane.

Now, let $C=\{(t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^n),\,t \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.

Since every nonzero polynomial with degree at most $n$ has at most $n$ roots, an affine hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains at most $n$ points in $C$.

So if you have a covering of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by proper affine subsets, you need at least $|\mathbb{R}|$ of them.